# Can we run memtestx86 on gem5 simulator?

Tags: memory, memory-management, gem5

Is it possible to run memtestx86 on Gem5 simulator.What changes we have to do in BIOS files,or any other way possible for this task.

Comment: Hi Prakhar, what have you tried and how did it fail? Why would you expect it not to work?

Comment: Well first i gave memtest image file as disk image in gem5 fs mode, but it was not compatible. Now i am working in gem5/src/src/x86/bios to find find how flow goes throught bios to disk image(operating system) so that rather than making it go to os i can direct it to memtest.